# `+` (смежный селектор) и `>` (селектор непосредственного потомка) не работают вместе

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Почему не работает селектор:

```
.parent > .child + .parent > .child {
    ...
}
```

Сниппет:

```css
.parent > .child + .parent > .child {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p class="child">текст</p>
  <p class="child">текст (почему не зелёный?)</p>
</div>
```

Чтобы заработало [можно заменить](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19701292) на `.parent > .child + .child`, но вопрос именно в том почему не работает исходная версия.

Comment: В css вроде же нет группировок, не?

Comment: нету, я хотел показать как ожидается интерпретирование этого селектора

Comment: @user268670 да в общем-то оно просто последовательное должно быть. Слева направо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В CSS нет никаких группировок, селекторы просто интерпретируются последовательно слева направо. Плюсик в вашем селекторе означает «следующий элемент после элемента `.parent > .child`»

```css
.parent > .child + .parent > .child {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Это .parent &gt; .child</div>
  <div class="parent">Это .parent &gt; .child + .parent
    <div class="child">Это .parent &gt; .child + .parent &gt; .child (зелёный!)</div>
  </div>
</div>
```